# Hide Status bar with if statement?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a QR code reader in my app.  Once the reader scans a code, it takes the app to a survey page.  I'm trying to get the survey page to hide the statusbar.  Here is my code:

```
- (void)zxingController:(ZXingWidgetController*)controller didScanResult:(NSString *)result {

   // self.resultsToDisplay = result;
    if (self.isViewLoaded) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yellaViewController" owner:self options:nil];
        initWithNibName:@"yellaViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        [topImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellalogoREAL.png"]];


        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    }
```

This isn't working for me, and the statusbar stays visible.  What am I doing wrong?

ALSO: Is there a way I can hide the tabbarcontroller on the surveypage using the same if statement?

Comment: Are you sure it enters the if statement? Also, check to see if status bar is being unhidden elsewhere in the code. What happens when you move that line of code to somewhere else? Does it work then?

Comment: When I move this line of code to the delegate as opposed to the .m, it works, but for every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ZxingController's viewDidAppear:  (ZxingWidgetController.m)

```
self.isStatusBarHidden = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden];
if (!isStatusBarHidden)
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

it cached the previous statusbar state, and when you exit the ZxingController, in viewDidDisappear:

```
if (!isStatusBarHidden)
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

Since the **viewDidDisappear in ZxingController will enter after zxingController:didScanResult:** 
So your setStatusBarHidden in zxingController:didScanResult: is no use.